# Línea entre el perímetro de dos círculos

Tags: svg, d3.js

Tengo una duda con D3.js y SVG, no consigo pintar una linea (`path` o `line`) entre el perímetro de dos circulos. Como se puede ver en la imagen que adjunto, la `line` se pinta hasta el centro.

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo limitar la línea?

Este es mi svg:

```html
<svg id="svgId" width="100%" height="100%" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
   <g transform="translate(567.5,0) scale(1)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
      <g id="PUESTO0">
         <circle cx="0px" cy="50px" r="3%" style="stroke-width: 1; stroke: green; fill: url(&quot;#image&quot;);"></circle>
         <text dx="-71" dy="90">EJEMPLO PUESTO ORIGEN</text>
      </g>
      <g id="PUESTO1">
         <circle cx="-200px" cy="150px" r="10.25px" style="stroke-width: 6; stroke: rgb(0, 0, 255);"></circle>
         <text dx="-271" dy="190">EJEMPLO PUESTO 1</text>
      </g>
      <g id="pathGroup">
         <path d="M -200 150 L 0 50" class="path" source="PUESTO0" target="PUESTO1" style="stroke: rgb(70, 130, 180); fill: none;"></path>
      </g>
   </g>
   <defs>
      <pattern id="image" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
         <image x="0%" y="0%" width="128" height="128" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://files.softicons.com/download/application-icons/circle-icons-add-on-2-by-martz90/png/128x128/playstation.png"></image>
      </pattern>
   </defs>
</svg>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ????? no Entiendo porque dices eso, cuando se trata de d3.js.

Comment: @JoseJavierSegura Existen muchas preguntas similares `svg` es más recientemente se abrió [esta pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44556/c%C3%B3mo-perfeccionar-borde-o-disminuir-grosor-de-imagen-svg) no es una tema **no relacionado** saludos.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El problema estaba en la transparencia de la imagen (.png), aunque se dibuja antes la linea en el DOM, la transparencia de la imagen hacia mostrar la linea que hay por debajo. Lo he solucionado quitando la transparencia a la imagen usando una herramienta externa.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear una máscara y aplicársela a la línea. Con la máscara se pintará sólo lo que esté en el espacio no coloreado por la misma (podrías verlo como una especie de inverso del clipPath).

El problema que me he encontrado es el `transform="translate(567.5,0) scale(1)"`, en especial el `translate`. Si lo quito (y actualizo los valores de las coordenadas X añadiéndole 567.5 a todo), funciona sin problemas. Tengo que ver cómo funcionaría con el `translate`.

Entonces la idea sería hacer algo como esto:

```html
<svg id="svgId" width="100%" height="100%" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
  <mask id="miMascara">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
    <circle cx="567.5px" cy="50px" r="3%" fill="black" />
    <circle cx="367.5px" cy="150px" r="10.25px" fill="black"/>
  </mask>
  <g style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
    
    <g id="PUESTO0">
      <circle cx="567.5px" cy="50px" r="3%" style="stroke-width: 1; stroke: green; fill: url(&quot;#image&quot;);"></circle>
      <text dx="496.5" dy="90">EJEMPLO PUESTO ORIGEN</text>
    </g>
    <g id="PUESTO1">
      <circle cx="367.5px" cy="150px" r="10.25px" style="stroke-width: 6; stroke: rgb(0, 0, 255);"></circle>
      <text dx="-296.5" dy="190">EJEMPLO PUESTO 1</text>
    </g>
    <g id="pathGroup">
      <path d="M 367.5 150 L 567.5 50" class="path" source="PUESTO0" target="PUESTO1" style="stroke: rgb(70, 130, 180); fill: none;" mask="url(#miMascara)"></path>
    </g>
  </g>
  <defs>
    <pattern id="image" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
      <image x="0%" y="0%" width="128" height="128" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://files.softicons.com/download/application-icons/circle-icons-add-on-2-by-martz90/png/128x128/playstation.png"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
</svg>
```