# ¿Cómo perfeccionar borde o disminuir grosor de imagen svg?

Tags: svg

Como puedo perfeccionar el borde de las imágenes a líneas menos fuerte o menos gruesa eliminando el grosor.

Me pueden explicar?

```html
<svg id="9b4dbafc-bcc6-4b4a-adde-826ab2107392" data-name="591408eb-8b74-4e6a-96a1-6811bcf8a314" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 165.63406 122.00001"><title>synerise-crm</title><rect y="0.00001" width="165.63406" height="122" style="fill:#fff;opacity:0"/><path d="M107.85443,119.8275c0.75272-34.62034-15.805-42.41714-52.68318-43.92234C18.2931,77.41036,2.48808,84.45455,2.48808,119.8275" transform="translate(27.63352 0.00001)" style="fill:none;stroke:#25bac7;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:4px"/><path d="M55.17126,53.178a25.37786,25.37786,0,0,0,25.589-25.1648q0.0018-.21215,0-0.42419C81.513,13.28927,69.47107,2,55.17126,2A25.589,25.589,0,0,0,55.17126,53.178Z" transform="translate(27.63352 0.00001)" style="fill:none;stroke:#9babb5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:4px"/></svg>
```

Pasar el borde las imágenes o las líneas del dibujo a un borde como esta imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Alguna fuente con ejemplos prácticos, ejemplos completos en la estructura o diseño de imagen `SVG`

Comment: @x-rw Gracias funciono, alguna fuente donde expliquen como crear dibujos svg es decir todo tipos de líneas o cual es el truco en dibujar mediante códigos.

Comment: talves te sirva esto http://gcoch.github.io/D3-tutorial/intro-svg.html

Comment: @x-rw sí gracias justo lo que necesitaba gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modificando el atributo `stroke-width`.

entonces `stroke-width:4px`

modifique a:
`stroke-width:0.5px`

**para volverlo mas delgado o mas grueso, ve probando modificando ese atributo**

```html
<svg id="9b4dbafc-bcc6-4b4a-adde-826ab2107392" data-name="591408eb-8b74-4e6a-96a1-6811bcf8a314" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 165.63406 122.00001"><title>synerise-crm</title><rect y="0.00001" width="165.63406" height="122" style="fill:#fff;opacity:0"/><path d="M107.85443,119.8275c0.75272-34.62034-15.805-42.41714-52.68318-43.92234C18.2931,77.41036,2.48808,84.45455,2.48808,119.8275" transform="translate(27.63352 0.00001)" style="fill:none;stroke:#25bac7;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:0.5px"/><path d="M55.17126,53.178a25.37786,25.37786,0,0,0,25.589-25.1648q0.0018-.21215,0-0.42419C81.513,13.28927,69.47107,2,55.17126,2A25.589,25.589,0,0,0,55.17126,53.178Z" transform="translate(27.63352 0.00001)" style="fill:none;stroke:#9babb5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:0.5px"/></svg>
```